# Laravel 7.x custom 500 isn't showing custom error view

Tags: php, laravel

I created this route to simulate a 500 internal server error:

```
Route::get('500', function () {
    abort(500);
});
```

I have made a 500.blade.php in my errors folder in my views like so:

```
app/resources/views/errors/500.blade.php
```

With just the word 'hello' in it.

Now when I go to app.test/500 I get the default laravel 500 error page instead of my custom 500 error page.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is your application in debug mode? (APP_DEBUG or DEBUG true?)

Comment: @apokryfos it's in true

Comment: Set it to false and try again. When it's in debug mode you'd normally get the exception stack trace instead of the default error pages

Comment: @apokryfos I just did, doesn't seem to make a difference (there isnt realy a trace, look at my route)

Comment: `abort` throws an HTTP exception which is why I mentioned that. Have you tried running `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-errors` first and then just modifying whatever was published?

Comment: @apokryfos yes I did, look in my question the path to my 500.blade.php